# A Gambling Game

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose you are playing a gambling game with $n$ people (including yourself), where $n>1$. Every person involved randomly rolls an integer between $1$ and $y$, where $y>0$ and is also an integer. If the number you roll is the lowest, then the amount that you pay to the winner is the absolute value of the difference between your number and his number. Additionally, if everyone rolls the same number, then no one exchanges any gold. There should be $y$ unique outcomes for which this could happen. If there are multiple winners, then the loser pays the same difference, but split up equally between the number of winners, $w$. If there are multiple losers, the winner receives the same difference, but each loser pays an equal portion to the winner.

From all of this, can you develop an expected value function for this gambling game? Also, can you calculate the formula for the standard deviation of rolls for a given game? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since it seems like a fair game, there should be no net gain or loss from individual players in the long run, if that helps.  (And there is an extra "I" at the end of the first paragraph)

Comment: That was my intuition, as well. I'm still curious if there is an expected value formula for this problem involving y and n, though. Also, i'm still clueless about what the standard deviation formula would look like.

Comment: There are $y+{y \choose 2}=\frac 12y(y+1)$ ways to choose the winning and losing numbers (which may be the same as you say).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an approach you can follow.  The chance that all the throws are the same is $\frac 1{y^{n-1}}$, which results in no payoff.  The chance that the payoff is $1$ is the chance that all the numbers are $k$ or $k+1$ for some choice of $k$.  There are $y-1$ choices, so the chance is $(y-1)\frac {2^n}{y^n}-2\frac 1{y^n}$ where the subtraction removes the two cases where all the numbers are the same.  The chance the payoff is $2$ is $(y-2)\frac{3^n}{y^n}-2\frac {2^n}{y^n}-3\frac 1{y^n}$ and so on.  From these probabilities you can find the variance for particular $y,n$, but I think a formula will be a big mess.