# A Gambling Game (Continued)

Tags: probability, gambling

I previously asked the following question: [A Gambling Game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815165/a-gambling-game)

For a brief summary, $ n>1 $ gamblers in a gambling game each are assigned a random integer in a specified interval $[1,y]$. Let $S$ be the highest random integer assigned and let $I$ be the lowest random integer assigned. The player assigned $S$ wins the game and earns $|S-I|$ dollars. In other words, the winner collects the range of the data set in winnings.

The crucial question: In the long run, does $|S-I|$ depend on $n$? In other words, do we expect the winnings to increase, decrease, or stay the same as the number of players in the game increases?

EDIT: $|S-I|$ seems to tend toward $y-1$ as $n$ grows. With 2 people, I imagine that the winnings average out around half of $y$, but then this value becomes larger (and tends toward $y-1$) as $n$ increases.

Now I am curious what kind of function would model ($n$, winnings) as $n$ ranges from $2$ to $y$ (or some other larger number).

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note this is very easy to simulate, so at least you can get a sense of the result.  Beyond that...well, if $n$ is very large then somebody will get the $1$ and someone else will get $y$.

Comment: should say: the rules aren't clear.  In particular, you don't say how ties should be handled.  My comment just assumes that you are interested in the distribution, or at least the expected value, of $|S-I|$.

Comment: Ah yes of course. $|S-I|$ would then seem to tend toward $y-1$ as n becomes larger. With 2 people, I imagine that the winnings average out around half of $y$, but then this value becomes larger as $n$ increases. I could probably add this to the original question, but now I am curious what kind of function would model ($n$, winnings) as $n$ ranges from $2$ to $y$ (or some other larger number).

Comment: I was hoping to leave out ties in this post to think about the simpler issue first, but in the old post I did describe how ties are handled. (It's just not as pretty).

Comment: Who gives money to player assigned with S? Player assigned with I or let's say "house"?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer to my question. To mee this looks like a zero-sum game with fluctuations in winnings lowering as number of players increasing.